# how to center crop a background image of linear layout?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Hi i had to make a layout with card with recyclerview so for that i set an image as a background to linear layout but now i'm unable to center crop that image
My problem is that i cannot use imageview because using that the height of card increases as well and i don't want that so please if someone can assit me..
my xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/primary_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="115dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/background_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:background="@drawable/club1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ellipse" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                        android:id="@+id/first_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="John Doe"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                        android:id="@+id/second_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="checked in to"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                        android:id="@+id/third_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="W south"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                        android:id="@+id/fourth_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                        android:text="beach mumbai"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                        android:id="@+id/fifth_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/second_text"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fourth_text"
                        android:text="30 mins ago."
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp">

            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:id="@+id/sixth_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="reply to abc............"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/favourite_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp" />

                <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                    android:id="@+id/seventh_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:text="40 likes"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: use margins for linearlayout

Comment: but i want to center crop image which is in linear layout

Comment: Use another linearlayout as a parent and use padding for that. For background , You cant use those image properties.

Comment: but even if i use padding using another linear layout that doesnt solve the problem of cropping

Comment: can you post screenshot what you expect and you got ?

Comment: Hi @Jyoti Jk i solved the issue but i've another issue can you help me out

Comment: yeah sure, What is the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169979/discussion-between-smith-and-jyoti-jk).

Answer (score 2):

You can't center crop a background image of linear layout,
But you can achieve the same using these changes:

1. Replace you LinearLayout with RelativeLayout
2. Place a ImageView as a first child inside relative layout and use property for center crop.

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/background_image"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="210dp"
   android:orientation="vertical">

       <ImageView
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:src="@drawable/club1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   .....
   ......
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you Want to control The Image View Scale

you need to put it in ImageView As Src Not Background

You can use Frame layout To Achieve it

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/primary_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="115dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/background_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/playstore_icon" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/first_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="John Doe"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/second_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="checked in to"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/third_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="W south"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/fourth_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                            android:text="beach mumbai"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/fifth_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/second_text"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fourth_text"
                            android:text="30 mins ago."
                            android:textSize="10sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="85dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sixth_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="reply to abc............"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/favourite_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_close" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/seventh_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:text="40 likes"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

CenterCrop logic is baked inside `ImageView`. The correct solution is to extract it into [a Drawable](https://gist.github.com/korniltsev/498d7b0687dfced86964ba6e232dee54) which wraps another Drawable and centerCrops it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `cardView` with `layout_height` and `layout_width` equal to `match_parent` and then add the `imageView` in it with `layout_height` and `layout_width` equals to `match_parent` then add your code after the image view in the card view with this you can use background centered crop image view without the needing of a relative layout, your code will looks like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Yoga">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/yoga"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"></ImageView>

   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use CoordinatorLayout, then just to put your ImageView with centerCrop parameter to top.

```
<CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <include layout="@layout/header_main" />

    <TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/white_border_background"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"/>

</AppBarLayout>

<ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</CoordinatorLayout>
```